# How to only include full months - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(amount) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         l.human_readable_id,
         DATE_TRUNC('day', c.created_date)::TIMESTAMP AS Date,
         (ROUND(c.amount/100.00, 2))::DOUBLE PRECISION AS amount,
         (ROUND(c.amount/100.00, 2)*0.04)::DOUBLE PRECISION AS Repayment,
         c.currency,
         c.payment_type,
         c.status,
         c.payment_id
     FROM 
         loan_applications AS l
     LEFT JOIN 
         merchants AS m ON l.merchant_id = m.id
     LEFT JOIN 
         codat_companies AS cc ON m.id = cc.merchant_id
     LEFT JOIN 
         codat_commerce_payments AS c ON cc.id = c.codat_company_id
     WHERE 
         amount IS NOT NULL) AS subquery 
GROUP BY 
    date
```

And get the sum of every month. Based on this, I can calculate the average. Is it possible to only include full months? For instance this is data from 1st of May 2021 until yesterday. But including this month would have a negative impact on the overall monthly average.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the actual requirement???

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition in the WHERE clause :

```
WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
  AND c.created_date < date_trunc('month', Now())
```